# Type punning between `pair<Key, Value>` and `pair<const Key, Value>`

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, type-punning

[A relative question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305793/is-it-possible-to-cast-a-pairkey-value-to-a-pairconst-key-value/64399851?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top), but I want a solution without any run-time overhead. (So constructing a new `pair` or using `std::variant` are not the answers)

---

Due to the potential template specialization, [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#:%7E:text=std%3A%3Apair,are%20not%20similar.) has said `pair<K, V>` and `pair<const K, V>` are not similar, that means a simple `reinterpret_cast` would trigger undefined behaviour.

```
auto p1 = pair<int, double>{ 1, 2.3 };
auto& p2 = reinterpret_cast<pair<const int, double>&>(p1); // UB!
```

---

Type-punning through `union` works fine in C, but not always legal in C++:

> - [It's undefined behavior to read from the member of the union that wasn't most recently written.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union#:%7E:text=It%27s%20undefined%20behavior%20to%20read%20from%20the%20member%20of%20the%20union%20that%20wasn%27t%20most%20recently%20written.)
> - [If members of a union are classes with user-defined constructors and destructors, to switch the active member, explicit destructor and placement new are generally needed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union#:%7E:text=If%20members%20of%20a%20union%20are%20classes%20with%20user%2Ddefined%20constructors%20and%20destructors%2C%20to%20switch%20the%20active%20member%2C%20explicit%20destructor%20and%20placement%20new%20are%20generally%20needed)

But there's an exception (to be consistent with behaviours in C?):

> [If two union members are standard-layout types, it's well-defined to examine their common subsequence on any compiler.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union#:%7E:text=If%20two%20union%20members%20are%20standard%2Dlayout%20types%2C%20it%27s%20well%2Ddefined%20to%20examine%20their%20common%20subsequence%20on%20any%20compiler.)

Since `Key` and `Value` may not be `standard-layout` and may have `non-trivial` destructor, it seems type-punning here is impossible, though members of `pair<Key, Value>` and `pair<const Key, Value>` could share the same ***lifetime*** (of course with alignment assertion).

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
union MapPair {
    using TrueType = pair<Key, Value>;
    using AccessType = pair<const Key, Value>;

    static_assert(
        offsetof(TrueType, first) == offsetof(AccessType, first)
     && offsetof(TrueType, second) == offsetof(AccessType, second)
     && sizeof(TrueType) == sizeof(AccessType)
    );

    TrueType truePair;
    AccessType accessPair;

    ~MapPair() {
        truePair.~pair();
    }

    // constructors for `truePair`
};

//...

auto mapPair = MapPair<NonTrivialKey, NonTrivialValue>{/*...*/};

// UB? Due to the lifetime of `truepair` is not terminated?
auto& accessPair = reinterpret_cast<pair<const NonTrivialKey, NonTrivialValue>&>(mapPair);

// still UB? Although objects on the buffer share the same constructor/destructor and lifetime
auto* accessPairPtr = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<pair<const NonTrivialKey, NonTrivialValue>*>(&mapPair));
```

---

I've noticed the guarantee that [no elements are copied or moved when calling `std::map::extract`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/extract#:%7E:text=no%20elements%20are%20copied%20or%20moved), and [user-defined specilization of `std::pair` would cause UB when operating `Node handle`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle#:%7E:text=For%20all%20map,.). So I trust some similar behaviours (type-punning or `const_cast`) really exist in the STL implementations relating to `Node handle`.

In `libc++`, it seems to depend on the characteristic of `clang` ([doesn't optimize for data members](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/f52318b47b333126c862d9a973d6e59ccaf713dc#)), not the standard.

`libstdc++` did the [similar work as `libc++`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/2dbe56bdfbf6c570cf23073f0c596da6bd1531c8), but no `std::launder` to refresh the type state.

`MSVC` is ... very surprising... and the commit history is too short that I can't find any reasons to support [such a simple aliasing](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/inc/xnode_handle.h#:%7E:text=//%20NB%3A%20Node,%3C_Pair_type%26%3E(_Data)%3B)...

---

Is there a standard way here?

Comment: Why do you want this at all? What is it you are trying to implement?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow `Node handle` in STL, or a map container like `SortedList` in C#. And I don't want to break the API compatibility (like pair<const K&, V&>)

Comment: The standard library isn’t constrained to use well-defined code as it can collude with the compiler.

Comment: Still makes no sense. Anything in the map must have a `const K` or your map can get corrupted from the outside. So if you hand out handles they must be `pair<const K&, V&>`. So just make everything `const K` so you don't even get internal corruption by accident.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Even node with `const K` still could get internal corruption by accident: `node._pair.~pair(); new(&(node.pair)) pair{wrongKey, value}`. And note that `Node handle` has no relation to its original container, it's an extracted one to be inserted into a new container, so its state should be modifiable.

Comment: Calling the destructor and then placement new you hardly do by accident. So finally we come to the real problem: You want to implement a `NodeHandle extract(Iterator)` like method? This is really unclear in your question.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Actually my question is just about if there's some workarounds about the behaviour. And in STL,  Node handle is the return type of methods like [`std::map::extract`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/extract). A detailed `Node handle`'s definition is [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible. The `node_handle` proposal mentioned this as a motivation for standardizing it:

> One of the reasons the Standard Library exists is to write non-portable and magical code that the client can’t write in portable C++ (e.g. , , <type_traits>, etc.). This is just another such example.

> Note that the `key` member function is the only place where such tricks are necessary, and that no changes to the containers or pair are required.

[ref](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0083r3.pdf)